# how to trigger spark job from java code with SparkSubmit.scala

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I saw oozie is using

```
List<String> sparkArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
sparkArgs.add("--master");
sparkArgs.add("yarn-cluster");
sparkArgs.add("--class");
sparkArgs.add("com.sample.spark.HelloSpark");
...
SparkSubmit.main(sparkArgs.toArray(new String[sparkArgs.size()]));
```

But when I ran this on cluster, I always got

> Error: Could not load YARN classes. This copy of Spark may not have been compiled with YARN support.

I think that is because my program can not find HADOOP_CONF_DIR. But how do I let SparkSubmit know that settings in Java code ?

Comment: what's your cluster settings ?

Comment: Why don't you use spark action?